# why the output not follow the setcursor?

Tags: arduino

Why is the output of the function does not follow the lcd.setCursor position? When type in, the output pops out at a different position instead of the determined setcursor. I need to use this function multiple times for different variables that hold a different number for a different purpose. However, I need the display of the numbers on the LCD according to the set position.

Here is the code:

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);  // Set the 
LCD I2C address


const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] =
{
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9,8,7,6}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {5,4,3}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(20,4);

}


void loop()
{   

    lcd.setCursor(2,0);
    int stage1speed = getnumber();
    lcd.setCursor(5,0);
    lcd.print("sv");

    lcd.setCursor(2,1);
    int stage1time = getnumber();
    lcd.setCursor(5,1);
    lcd.print("sec");

     lcd.setCursor(2,2);
    int stage2speed = getnumber();
    lcd.setCursor(5,2);
    lcd.print("sec");

    lcd.setCursor(2,3);
    int stage2time = getnumber();
    lcd.setCursor(5,3);
    lcd.print("sec");

}


int getnumber()
{

    static char buffer[4];
    static byte i = 0;

    char key = keypad.getKey();

    // i < 3: prevent buffer overflow
    if  ('0' <= key && key <= '9' && i < 3)
    {
        buffer[i] = key;
        ++i;

    } else if (key == '#' && i > 0) 
     {
        buffer[i] = '\0'; // null-terminate buffer
        int value = atoi(buffer);
        lcd.print(buffer);
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already told you to debug your code by printing to serial.

Comment: Printing it to serial seem to do nothing. It only shows constant flow of number. I want it to appear according to the Setcursor.  The value jumps all over the lcd.